# Pushing an object to beginning of an array

Tags: javascript

I have this array.

```
var array = [
 {
  title:'Fish'
  id: 1
 },
 {
  title: 'Meat'
  id:2
 }
]
```

It's used in a drop down. I'd like to add an option at the top:

```
{
  title:'All'
  id:3
}
```

How do I push this object to the beginning of the array? If I use push, then it's placed at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)** method of the javascript `array`:

```
array.unshift({title: 'All', id: 3})
```